# Concat mp4 videos and merge their audios to the final output

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have several videos and photos and need to merge them with the cross-dissolve effect. The algorithm is next:

1. Create videos from images and add silent audio to them (so they will also have a sound stream):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -loop 1 -i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/ea5c93fd-d946-4742-b8f7-ea9ae4d43441.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=750:1280  /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/ea5c93fd-d946-4742-b8f7-ea9ae4d43441.mp4
```

2. Combine all the videos and audios into one using this command:

```
ffmpeg 
-i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/temp_68d437c0-f5e2-4651-b07e-91533480b6ef.mp4 
-i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/temp_48f3c111-610d-40c7-ac71-6ce2fbb16184.mp4 
-i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/temp_1593b5d8-7e16-417d-9372-2267581cd504.mp4 
-i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/temp_1ac7f6be-1b12-4e31-b904-1491cc9b9494.mp4 
-i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-19-Wednesday-05-40-34/temp_ea5c93fd-d946-4742-b8f7-ea9ae4d43441.mp4  
-filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=start=0:end=8.032,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip0];
[1:v]trim=start=2:end=13.047,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip1];
[2:v]trim=start=2:end=13.558,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip2];
[3:v]trim=start=2:end=13.186,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip3];
[4:v]trim=start=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip4];
[0:v]trim=start=9.032:end=10.032,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out0];
[1:v]trim=start=14.047:end=15.047,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out1];
[2:v]trim=start=14.558:end=15.558,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out2];
[3:v]trim=start=14.186:end=15.186,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out3];
[1:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in1];
[2:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in2];
[3:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in3];
[4:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in4];
[in1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein1];
[in2]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein2];
[in3]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein3];
[in4]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein4];
[out0]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout0];
[out1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout1];
[out2]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout2];
[out3]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout3];
[fadein1]fifo[fadein1fifo];
[fadein2]fifo[fadein2fifo];
[fadein3]fifo[fadein3fifo];
[fadein4]fifo[fadein4fifo];
[fadeout0]fifo[fadeout0fifo];
[fadeout1]fifo[fadeout1fifo];
[fadeout2]fifo[fadeout2fifo];
[fadeout3]fifo[fadeout3fifo];
[fadeout0fifo][fadein1fifo]overlay[crossfade0];
[fadeout1fifo][fadein2fifo]overlay[crossfade1];
[fadeout2fifo][fadein3fifo]overlay[crossfade2];
[fadeout3fifo][fadein4fifo]overlay[crossfade3];
[clip0][crossfade0][clip1][crossfade1][clip2][crossfade2][clip3][crossfade3][clip4]concat=n=9[output];
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[A1];
[A1][2:a]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[A2];
[A2][3:a]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[A3];
[A3][4:a]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio] " 
-vsync 0 -map "[output]" -map "[audio]" /tmp/media/final/some_filename_d0d2aab0-792a-4540-b2d3-e64abe98bf5c.mp4
```

And all works pretty well, but if I have, for example:

- picture
- video
- video
- picture

Then the sound from the second video is mapping to the first picture and sound from the third video to second video. And the third video actually goes without sound.

It seems like it's happening because the silent sound of the first picture is pretty short. An I right?
If so, how can I increase its duration?

I would much appreciate any help with this!

Comment: In your video trims, you have omitted one second from each video stream e.g. 8.032 to 9.032 from `0:v` but audio is fully used. That will cause a mismatch in duration. In general, your audio needs to be correspondingly trimmed, and your acrossfade duration should match the video crossfade duration. With 4.3, you can simplify most of the video filtering with xfade filter.

Comment: @Gyan got this. I've thought about this possible mismatch. Thanks for your explanation.
By the way, I don't yet understand why the video starts with a sound when it should be silent for first 10 seconds.

Comment: And I would be very thankful if you could provide a code example of how I can simplify this with crossfade. For now, it seems for as almost impossible thing to handle all the mismatches in the duration properly

Comment: What is the duration of all inputs? Describe the intended output.

Comment: @Gyan actually the duration is changeable. I am writing a python script to generate the needed FFmpeg command. The input is some photos and videos. Durations can be whatever is specified in the parameters to python script. For now, I just need an example of a command to understand how it should look like. Then I'll modify the script accordingly

Comment: Provide the duration for one set of inputs.

Comment: @Gyan let's say [10s, 10s, 10s, 10s, 10s] - the duration list for input videos (the first and the last videos will not have the audio stream. And [2s, 2s, 2s, 2s, 2s] - the duration list for cross-disolve effects.

Comment: @Gyan is it still possible to get the example of a script from you? I would be much thankful!

Comment: Within a day or so.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks! Looking forward too see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 5 inputs of 10 seconds each, all with audio streams*, with ffmpeg 4.3 or newer, use the xfade and acrossfade filters.

```
ffmpeg 
-i in1.mp4 
-i in2.mp4 
-i in3.mp4 
-i in4.mp4 
-i in5.mp4  
-filter_complex 
"  [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=8[V01];
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=16[V02];
 [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=24[V03];
 [V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=32[video];
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];
 [A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" 
-vsync 0 -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" out.mp4
```

*if there's no existing audio stream, add one using the command in step 1.

If the existing audio stream of a file isn't 10 seconds long, use these filters on it before acrossfade.

```
[input]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:10[filtered]
```

and then use this filtered stream as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That might me helpful